# How to configure openfire to connect mysql cluster

Tags: openfire, mysql-cluster

I want the high availability of database for my Openfire server. Hence, I have successfully created a mysql cluster. But I am not able to configure Openfire to use that mysql cluster.
I have searched about it but not able to find much except using the following connection string :  `"jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://" + hosts + "/test"`.
But this does not seems to work.
Please help me to configure my Openfire server to use mysql cluster. Any kind of help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what does not seems to work for you? Are you getting any error?

You can refer the following link for openfire installation with mysql: 

http://mindbowser.com/blog/openfire-installation-and-database-configuration/